# Windows 10 has no clarity in my device

Tags: windows-10

I installed windows 10 but it has no clarity in my system. I have an Radeon HD 550v and its driver catalyst.when I looked device manager and viewed display adapters it showed Microsoft basic display adapter.I also have a old driver for this graphic card,I don't have good internet connection.so can anyone tell me the version of graphic driver suitable for windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the old driver using compatibility mode, then at device manager right click the driver that already installed and click update driver software then click search automatically.

Comment: Will it require internet connection

Comment: when install old driver, you do not need internet connection but the driver should works well, when update the software, yes you need internet connection.

Comment: So is it sure that I will get my clarity to windows 10